# how to pass multiple objects into mailer/email contents in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

When an user makes a post (sub_opp) I send the user an email.  However, I would like to include in the email the sport (column in sub_opp model).  I am getting an undefined method error on sub_opp when it hits the mailer in the example below.

Controller where sub_opp is created

```
def create
@sub_opp = SubOpp.new(sub_opp_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @sub_opp.save
    user = User.find_by_id(@sub_opp.user_id)
    sub_opp = @sub_opp
    UserMailer.posted_subopp_email(user, sub_opp).deliver
    .... continued
```

Mailer controller

```
  def posted_subopp_email(user, sub_opp)
    mail( :to => user.email,  :subject => 'You made a post!' )
  end
```

Mailer view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>You posted to the sub feed!</h3>
    <p>You made a post.</p>
    <p><%= sub_opp.sport %></p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Why doesn't the <%= sub_opp.sport %> work in this example?  Sport is a column in the sub_opp model.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an instance variable first. Instance variables will be available in your mailer view.

Consider your mailer a controller in MVC.

```
def posted_subopp_email(user, sub_opp)
  @sub_opp = sub_opp
  @user = user
  mail( :to => user.email,  :subject => 'You made a post!' )
end
```

Then access it like in you would in your views

```
<body>
  <h3>You posted to the sub feed!</h3>
  <p>You made a post.</p>
  <p><%= @sub_opp.sport %></p>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked.  I did not need to add @user = user but to access the subopp i did.  Thank you!

Comment: Indeed you don't need the `@user` with your current view. But then why do you give it to `posted_subopp_email`? Might as well remove that

Comment: I actually did need it.  I did not understand the concept that the instance variables in the mailer were what was required to show this in the email.  THanks for the help.